# How to insert a frame for a page in latex?

Tags: margins, border

I need to create a frame for a page in a latex document. My document have frame with 3 cm of margin.  It will have a text in the top, other in the center, and in the footer.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without extra packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry} 
\begin{document}
\fboxsep1em
\fboxrule2pt
\noindent\fbox{\begin{minipage}
[c][\dimexpr\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule]
[c]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
Text
\vfill
Text
\vfill
Text
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good! It perfectly worked! Thak you.

Answer (score 4):

You could overlay a rectangle with TikZ (which needs two LaTeX runs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \draw ([xshift=3cm,yshift=-3cm]current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-3cm,yshift=3cm]current page.south east);
Text
\vfill
Text
\vfill
Text
\end{document}
```