# Overlap order among text, \backgroundcolor and \tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, text, overlap, backgroundcolor

I have the following document layout, composed of a 2-column text (here only the left column has some text), a gray background stripe over the left column of the document and a yellow frame at te border of the entire page:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
        left   = 0.2cm,
        right  = 0.2cm,
        top    = 0.1cm,
        bottom = 0.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\backgroundcolor{c[0](5pt,3pt)(0.5\columnsep,3pt)}[rgb]{0.95,0.95,0.95}

\begin{document}

% Yellow frame
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452538/how-to-insert-a-frame-for-a-page-in-latex
\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \draw[draw=yellow,line width=0.7cm] ([xshift=0cm,yshift=-0cm]current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-0cm,yshift=0cm]current page.south east);

% 2-column text
\columnratio{0.4}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\lipsum[1-3]
% \switchcolumn 
\lipsum[2-6]
\end{paracol}
```

[image]
[image]

But I would like to have the text as the first/top layer, the yellow frame as second/intermediate layer, and the gray background as third/bottom layer, as in this figure (produced with power point):
[image]

**How to get this overlap among the three layers, in the described order?**

Comment: If you want the yellow frame between text and gray box, you can't place text the text inside the gray box. Just as you would need to construct this with PowerPoint, you would need to create two boxes, one for the gray background and one for the text (and then also the yellow frame of course).

Answer (score 1):

my attempt...

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
        left=0.2cm,
        right=0.2cm,
        top=0.1cm,
        bottom=0.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}


% Yellow frame first on  bottom layer
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[draw=yellow,line width=0.7cm] ([xshift=0cm,yshift=-0cm]current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-0cm,yshift=0cm]current page.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

% Gray background in second layer <= Adjust the dimensions and position to fit your layout
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[gray!30] (0.2cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (\textwidth-0.4cm,-\textheight+0.3cm); % Adjust these dimensions
\end{tikzpicture}

% your text content finally so it appears on top
\columnratio{0.4}
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \lipsum[2-6]
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

---

**EDITED**: The accepted answer of @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz in the follow up question "[tikzpicture moves the text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/713468/tikzpicture-moves-the-text)", is what I was looking for. Many thanks also to @JeT for the first great hint and attempt!

---

Thanks @JeT, quite close... the yellow frame was switched with the gray background..

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
        left=0.2cm,
        right=0.2cm,
        top=0.1cm,
        bottom=0.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

% Gray background at the bottom
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[gray!30] ([xshift=0cm,yshift=-0cm]current page.north west) rectangle  ([xshift=-12.5cm,yshift=0cm]current page.south east); % Adjust these dimensions
\end{tikzpicture}

% Yellow frame as a second layer
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[draw=yellow,line width=0.7cm] ([xshift=0cm,yshift=-0cm]current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-0cm,yshift=0cm]current page.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

% Text on top
\columnratio{0.4}
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \noindent\lipsum[1-3]
    \noindent\lipsum[2-6]
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**However, there is still the issue about how to make the text of lipsum start at the top left corner... Indeed, it looks like that the `tikzpicture` moves the text down...**

(I tried several times, but I am not able to solve this issue - I therefore opened a [new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/713468/tikzpicture-moves-the-text))