# tikzpicture moves the text

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, text

This is a follow up question of [Overlap order among text, \backgroundcolor and \tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/713408/overlap-order-among-text-backgroundcolor-and-tikz/713425#713425).

In the following example, how to make the text of lipsum start at the top left corner of the page?

Indeed, it looks like that tikzpicture moves the text down...

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
        left=0.2cm,
        right=0.2cm,
        top=0.1cm,
        bottom=0.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

% Gray background at the bottom
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[gray!30] ([xshift=0cm,yshift=-0cm]current page.north west) rectangle  ([xshift=-12.5cm,yshift=0cm]current page.south east); % Adjust these dimensions
\end{tikzpicture}

% Yellow frame as a second layer
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[draw=yellow,line width=0.7cm] ([xshift=0cm,yshift=-0cm]current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-0cm,yshift=0cm]current page.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

% Text on top
\columnratio{0.4}
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \noindent\lipsum[1-3]
    \noindent\lipsum[2-6]
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried tcolorbox? This  might be easier with that package, rather than tikz.

Comment: Remove the empty lines

Comment: @PaulA, hi, never used tcolorbox..

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, hi, which empty lines? Where?

Comment: @Ommo The empty lines between your tikz pictures

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, thanks, I removed the empty line between the two ```tikzpicture```... Yes, the text goes up, but not completely as without both the ```tikzpicture```....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of problems:

- the empty line between the tikzpictures will start a new paragraph (why two tikzpictures in the first place?)
- if you don't want to have an additional line before you start your paracols, place the tikzpicture at the start of the columns instead of before them.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
        left=0.2cm,
        right=0.2cm,
        top=0.1cm,
        bottom=0.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

% Text on top
\columnratio{0.4}
\begin{paracol}{2}
% Gray background at the bottom
    \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \fill[gray!30] (current page.north west) rectangle  ([xshift=-12.5cm]current page.south east); % Adjust these dimensions
      \draw[draw=yellow,line width=0.7cm] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \noindent\lipsum[2-6]
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Woww! An amazing touchdown, thanks!

Comment: @Ommo You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For generating dummy text
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} % Load tcolorbox package

\newtcolorbox{outerbox}{
    colback=white, % Background color
    colframe=yellow, % Border color
    width=\textwidth, % Width of the box
    height fixed for=all, % Dynamically adjust height
    valign=center, % Vertical alignment
    halign=center, % Horizontal alignment
    fonttitle=\bfseries, % Font for the title
    title={}, % Title of the box
    enhanced, % Enhanced mode for more styling options
    boxrule=5pt % Thickness of the frame
}


% Define tcolorbox for the inner grey columns
\newtcolorbox{innerbox}{
    colback=gray!20!white, % Background color
    colframe=gray!70!black, % Border color
    width=\linewidth, % Width of the box
    height fill, % Allow box to expand vertically to fit content
    valign=center, % Vertical alignment
    halign=left, % Horizontal alignment
    breakable % Allow breaking across pages
}

\begin{document}

\begin{outerbox}
    \begin{minipage}[b][0.5\textheight]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{innerbox}
            \lipsum[1] % Dummy text for the left column
        \end{innerbox}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill % Space between columns
    \begin{minipage}[b][0.8\textheight]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{innerbox}
            \lipsum[4] % Dummy text for the right column (extended)
        \end{innerbox}
    \end{minipage}
\end{outerbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Paul A! :-) (+1)